# cannot assign to `self.input.cached_token` because it is borrowed

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use the crate `google-somethin = "0.1.4"` Here is my Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "test_json"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
google-somethin = "0.1.4"
openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }
```

I have the following error when I try to build

```
cannot assign to `self.input.cached_token` because it is borrowed
   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cssparser-0.24.1/src/parser.rs:572:17
    |
547 |     pub fn next_including_whitespace_and_comments(&mut self) -> Result<&Token<'i>, BasicParseError<'i>> {
    |                                                   - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
560 |             Some(ref cached_token)
    |                  ---------------- borrow of `self.input.cached_token` occurs here
...
572 |                 self.input.cached_token = Some(CachedToken {
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `self.input.cached_token` occurs here
...
584 |         Ok(token)
    |         --------- returning this value requires that `self.input.cached_token.0` is borrowed for `'1`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0506`.
error: could not compile `cssparser`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I have this error when `Compiling cssparser v0.24.1`

Comment: What is your rustc version? You might have a version before lifetimes were relaxed in some way to allow that code to compile.

Comment: Thanks for you answer , my version is rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)

Comment: I can recreate this error with `rustc 1.57.0-nightly (5b210643e 2021-10-11)`. But `cssparser` `0.24.1` isn't the latest version. It's being pulled in by `scraper` `0.8.2`, which also isn't the latest version, but in turn it is being pulled in by `google-somethin` `0.1.4`, which is the latest version. I think if `google-somethin` updated their `scraper` dependency this would be fixed, although I'm not sure why it's even failing on an old version of the library, wonder if this happens with previous compiler versions or if it's a recent regression?

Comment: Thanks again , I understand now the cause of the problem , is there  any solution to update the scraper dependency so that I can use google-somethin?

Comment: I don't believe so, `google-somethin` uses `scraper = ^0.8.1`, which I think restricts it to at most `0.8.*`, below the `0.12` latest version. You'd have to fork over `google-somethin` to modify it's dependencies and fix any fallout from the updates.